# Regex for non-alphanumeric delimiters (not \W)

Tags: .net, regex, alphanumeric

I have probably *completely* missed something, but here is what I have:

1. -- Need to prevent inadvertent release of phone numbers.
2. -- all numbers in the form nnn-nnnn
3. -- may or may not be delimited (e.g, tab, comma, space, whatever)
4. -- do NOT block journal articles or study numbers having similar (but not identical) form -- for example
       xxxnnn-nnnnxxx (yeah, sort of    contradicts 'delimited', but "x"
       are alphanumeric only )

So, I have

`(\A|\s|\W)\d{3}-\d{4}(\Z|\s|\W)`

Which works!  *Almost* the way I want.  Almost.
However, `\W` is `^a-zA-Z0-9_` and `_` is a potential delimiter.  Already tried replacing `\W` with `^a-zA-Z0-9` with no success (actually, worse), but perhaps specified improperly?
FWIW, this will be evaluated by .NET engine.

Comment: Already tried replacing \W with ^a-zA-Z0-9 with no success (actually, worse), but perhaps specified improperly => post the code you had when you tried that

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(\A|\s|[^a-zA-Z0-9])\d{3}-\d{4}(\Z|\s|[^a-zA-Z0-9])
```

Comment: Looks like it does it!  Thanks.  To Tolanj, who obviously suspected this as well, I had specified the characters incorrectly.  Thanks to all who contributed.

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative lookbehind `(?<!...)` and a negative lookahead `(?!...)`:

```
(?<![^\W_])[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}(?![^\W_])
```

Comment: I like this, but suspect it will be difficult for others to support.  Thankyou, however.